# Can you pass a variable to the data property in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the HighCharts js library to draw a chart. What I would like to do is pass to a data property a variable. it's possible? And how should one proceed?

This is my variable:

```
formattedSeries = [[1, 1], [2, 0.5], [3, 0.3]];
```

and I'm trying to do this:

```
initLapChart() {
hcharts.chart(this.div.nativeElement, { 
  ...
  series: [{
    data: this.formattedSeries
  }]
});
```

Comment: `this` is a reference to function context. Unless `formattedSeries` is defined in mentioned context, it will be undefined.

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zn2arfhg/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but I believe the way you refer to the defined variable is wrong. `this` refers to the context of current scope (function). Remove it

```
var formattedSeries = [[1, 1], [2, 0.5], [3, 0.3]];

function initChart(){ 

   Highcharts.chart('container', { 
     series: [{
        data: formattedSeries
// ______________^ reference to global scope
     }]
   });

}
```